# center align facebook login window

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am trying to implement `Facebook` login in my application using the Javascript SDK. I am using the following js:

```
$("#loginWithFacebook").click(function () {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.api('/me', function (user_details) {
               // do something with the user_details
            });
        }
    });
```

The problem is when I call `FB.login`, it opens the Facebook login window to the extreme right, but I want it to be center aligned. Any way to fix this issue?

Comment: can you post a test link where this is happening?

Comment: @luschn I do not have server access to server so I cannot give a test link...I have also noticed that the popup works fine when using `<fb:login-button>`...any way to use custom styling on this?

Comment: are you using localhost? anyway, FB.login works fine in general and you can´t center it on your own afaik.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I'm faced with the same issue :
when using simple custom `<button>` instead of "official" FB button, the login popup window opens on extreme right of screen.

I think the official button (wich is complex : a complete html page with JS) makes use of the SDK for centering the popup. I couldn't manage to use the SDK for centering popup with a custom button (if someone does, tell us!).
The FB.login() function doesn't center popup when fired from custom button.

I found this solution, which works great :
http://permadi.com/2011/04/centering-facebook-oath-login-popup-dialog/

the online demo (view source to see code) :
http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/facebook-js-oauth-popup-centered/index.html

It makes use of FB.getLoginStatus() and NOT FB.login().
It mimics the FB.login function :

- open centered facebook popup with window.open
- check with setInterval if user is logged or not
- when user is finished with facebook, the redirectUrl provided during opening the popup is used by FB go to a blank page we create with only window.close() in it  --> it closes the popup
- clearInterval and continue with app code (login, save in data base...)

---

Below is **my** JQUERY version of their script with some simplification and improvments :

- simplification : only login button. No logout.
- improvment : load JSK only if user hit the FBlogin button (and only once)
- improvment : prevent user from triggering multiple facebook popup (important)

We kind of recreate the offical FB.login function here:)
But there is some advantages over the offical button :

- we can use a simple `<button>` wich is very easy to style
- wich is accessible (try to catch official btn with TAB on keyboard only)
- wich loads fast

  ```
  var fbOpen = 0; // to prevent opening multiple facebook login popup dialog
  // otherwhise setInterval is messing things around!

  function treatFBresponse() {
          FB.init({
                  appId : 'YOUR_APDD_ID',
                  status :true, // IMPORTANT, otherwhise if user cancel login (->response.status="unknown), 2nd time -> response.status="NULL" -> no possible login any more!
                  cookie : true,
                  version : 'v2.5'
          });

          FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                  if (response.status=="connected" && response.authResponse){
                          FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,picture,email', function(response) {
                          // USER LOGGED into your app and facebook -> console.dir(response); -> log into your app, save in database etc.

                  }else{
                          // USER NOT LOGGED into your app
                          fbOpen = 0; // we let him retry
                  }
          });
  }

  var gotFBscript = 0; // to load FB JS SDK only once

  function fbSDK() {
          // SDK NOT LOADED YET
          if( !gotFBscript){
                  console.log('getting FB JS SDK...');

                  $.ajax({        
                  // OR   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
                  //      $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_EN/sdk.js', function(){ gotFBscript = 1 ...
                  // BUT  $.ajax is better I think because it lets you set cache to true locally
                    url: '//connect.facebook.net/en_EN/sdk.js',
                    dataType: "script",
                    cache:true,
                    success: function() {

                          gotFBscript = 1;
                          treatFBresponse();

                    }
                  });

          // SDK ALREADY LOADED
          }else if ( gotFBscript ){
                  treatFBresponse();
          }
  };

  function facebookPopup() {
          var popupWidth=500,
              popupHeight=300,
              xPosition=($(window).width()-popupWidth)/2,
              yPosition=($(window).height()-popupHeight)/2,
              loginUrl="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?"+
                  "scope=public_profile,email&"+  // instead of publish_stream
                  "api_key=YOUR_APDD_ID&"+        // instead of client_id
                  "redirect_uri=http://www.MY_SITE.COM/path/to/self-closing-empty-page.php&"+
                  "response_type=token&"+
                  "display=popup",

              fbLoginWindow=window.open(loginUrl, "LoginWindow", 
                  "location=1,scrollbars=1,"+
                  "width="+popupWidth+",height="+popupHeight+","+
                  "left="+xPosition+",top="+yPosition),

              loginTimer=setInterval( function() { checkLoginWindowClosure(fbLoginWindow, loginTimer), 1000);
  };

  function checkLoginWindowClosure(fbLoginWindow, loginTimer) { 
          if (fbLoginWindow.closed) 
          {
                  clearInterval(loginTimer);
                  fbSDK();
          }
  };

  $("#YOUR_CUSTOM_FB_BUTTON").on('click', function() {
          if(fbOpen === 0) {
                  fbOpen = 1;
                  facebookPopup();
          }
  });
  ```

Answer (score -2):

You should read this [link](http://hayageek.com/facebook-javascript-sdk/). You can just use the correct HTML Tags with `<div align="center">` or use CSS